# how to observe new or destroyed assocation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

I know there's the after_add and after_remove association callbacks you can use when defining the association in rails as described under the Assocation Callbacks section here - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

But the gem i'm using already defined the association like so:

has_many :payments, as: :source

I tried going with class_eval or ActiveSupport::Concern to override the association so it would look like this:

has_many :payments, as: :source, after_add: :payment_added, after_remove: :payment_removed

But it isn't working for me (if you think it should let me know)

So rather than trying to override it i'm wondering if there's any other way to observe something similar to after_remove and after_add, basically when a payment has been added or removed.

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks don't have to be defined on the association definition line. They can be added at any time to the associated object - especially if they are only added to this associated object.

Here's a link to the [docs on callbacks here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)

To replace your `after_add` callback what you want is an `after_create` callback. and your `after_remove` you could use `after_destroy`

eg:

```
has_many :payments, as: :source
```

and in payments:

```
after_create :payment_added
after_destroy :payment_removed
```

Now - you've moved it into the child object, you may need to adjust the logic to call a method on the parent object... also, if these payments can be added to something other than the main object it might not work, but it's an option.

Comment: They are slightly different, but you can still (probably) repurpose them for your uses if you need to.

Comment: that's not going to work because for existing credit cards after_create will not be called if a new payment has been added to a credit cards list of payments. After create here will only be called if a new credit card has been created. I want to be notified if a new payment has been added to the credit card list of payments made

Comment: ah no - perhaps I was not clear enough. I didn't mean to put the after_create into the credit card model, but into the payment model. it will then happily tell you when a new payment has been created... and you can then check if it's been added to a credit-card. No - it's not exactly the same but as I said, it can be repurposed to do most fo the things you might need to do...

Comment: ok, but i will need to leave this question open as i'm directly looking for an answer to my problem. thanks so much for your input anyways